# Separate values of one column into multiple columns based on other column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this with only two columns:

```
Table: Employees

+----------+-------------+
|Employee  | Designation |
+----------+-------------+
| Ron      | Manager     |
| James    | HR          |
| Toby     | Clerk       |
| Amanda   | Clerk       |
| Jenny    | Manager     |
| Quentin  | HR          |
| Roger    | Manager     |
| Harry    | Clerk       |
| Sunny    | Clerk       |
| Rachael  | Manager     |
+----------+-------------+
```

I need to write a query to output results like this:

```
+-----------+--------- +------------+
| Manager   |  HR      |   Clerk    |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| Jenny     |  James   |   Amanda   |
| Rachael   |  Quentin |   Harry    |
| Roger     |  null    |   Sunny    |
| Ron       |  null    |   Toby     |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

The employees must be separated into different column based on their designation and ordered alphabetically. There are solutions on the net but most of them either create a new table with an id column with this data in order to solve the problem. Is there a simple solution as an SQL query to solve this without creating any new table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and some sort of pivoting.  I prefer conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when designation = 'Manager' then employee end) as Manager,
       max(case when designation = 'HR' then employee end) as HR,
       max(case when designation = 'Clerk' then employee end) as Clerk  
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by designation order by employee) as seqnum
      from employees e
     ) e
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```